# AWS Gateway and CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I seem to have an issue with seeing logs in AWS CloudWatch for my AWS Gateway.

I did the following:

- created IAM role that allows for CloudWatch logs
- created API and set IAM ARN in the API settings
- Enabled CloudWatch Logs in the stage settings

Now I can see a Log Group that seem to correspond to my AWS Gateway and Log Streams but all of them are empty.

I think I'm missing something here.

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: is this vpc gateway or api gateway? (vpc flow logs | enable api traces in api logging )

Comment: @Michal, If you liked the answer and it worked for you, kindly approve it and upvote it as well as recommended by Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set up API Logging Using the API Gateway Console**

To set up API logging, you must have deployed the API to a stage. You must also have configured [an appropriate CloudWatch Logs role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html) ARN for your account.

1. Sign in to the API Gateway console at [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway).
2. Choose Settings from the primary navigation panel and type an ARN of an IAM role with appropriate permissions in CloudWatch log role ARN.
   You need to do this once.
3. Do one of the following:

   - Choose an existing API and then choose a stage.
   - Create an API and deploy it to a stage.
4. Choose Logs/Tracing in the Stage Editor.
5. To enable execution logging:

   1. Choose Enable CloudWatch Logs under CloudWatch Settings.
   2. Choose Error or Info from the dropdown menu.
   3. If desired, choose Enable Detailed CloudWatch Metrics.

For more information about CloudWatch metrics, see [Monitor API Execution with Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html).

6. To enable access logging:

   1. Choose to Enable Access Logging under Custom Access Logging.
   2. Type the ARN of a log group in CloudWatch Group. The ARN format is arn:aws:logs:{region}:{account-id}:log-group:API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{rest-api-id}/{stage-name}.
   3. Type a log format in Log Format. You can choose CLF, JSON, XML, or CSV to use one of the provided examples as a guide.
7. Choose Save Changes.

*Note: You can enable execution logging and access logging independent of each other.*

Reference: [Set Up CloudWatch API Logging in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html)

Comment: great answer. If I only toggle "Enable Detailed CloudWatch Metrics" do I have to re-deploy the API for the change to take effect?

Comment: It will happen automatically as you select an existing API along with the stage for deployment before toggling "Enable Detailed CloudWatch Metrics" and then select "Save Changes".